# getElementsByTagName not working in chrome and safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari, getelementsbytagname

I'm using the javascript method getElementsByTagName("a") to call all 'a' tags and do some effect with them. The method works in FF and Opera but not in Chrome and Safari.
When I look in the debugging tools of Chrome and Safari they say: ***"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null"***

Why is that and what's the fix? Please can someone advise me on this?

Many Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
function popUpSAPWindow(){
// Find all links in the page and put them into an array.
var linksInOrderLinesTable = document.getElementById("orderLinesTable").getElementsByTagName("a"); // The line doing the error
var linksLen = linksInOrderLinesTable.length;

// If the link text is 'SAP' then modify the attributes
for(var i = 0; i < linksLen; i++){
    if(linksInOrderLinesTable[i].innerHTML == "SAP"){
        // Store the 'href' value of each SAP link.
        var sapHref = linksInOrderLinesTable[i].href;

        // Modify the attributes of each SAP link.      
        linksInOrderLinesTable[i].setAttribute("href", "javascript:return false;");
        linksInOrderLinesTable[i].setAttribute("onclick", "sapNewWindow(\'" + sapHref + "\')");
    }
}
```

}

It works with this HTML:

```
<table id="orderLinesTable" summary="List of orders made by customers that the administrator can pick and deal with">
<tr>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Basket id</th>
    <th>Order line id</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Catalogue</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Details</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Accepted</td>
    <td>236569</td>
    <td>207</td>
    <td>OS Master Map</td>
    <td>NHS</td>
    <td>Standard</td>
    <td>1 Aug 10</td>
    <td><a href="/orderLineDetails.html">Normal</a> <a href="/orderLineDetails.html">SAP</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>New</td>
    <td>236987</td>
    <td>528</td>
    <td>Code-Point</td>
    <td>BT</td>
    <td>Standard</td>
    <td>9 Aug 10</td>
    <td><a href="/orderLineDetails.html">Normal</a> <a href="/orderLineDetails.html">SAP</a></td>
</tr>
```

But when I'm on other pages it gives the error mentioned.

Comment: That error suggests it's not really the method itself, but the object you're trying to call it on, which is null (and therefore does not have the method). Can you post your javascript code?

Comment: Ok, I'll post it now, see underneath the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that when you're calling `document.getElementById("orderLinesTable").getElementsByTagName("a")` on a page that does not have the `orderLinesTable` getElementById will return `null`. Therefore calling `getElementsByTagName` on `null` will yield an error.

This should solve the problem:

```
var orderLinesTable = document.getElementById("orderLinesTable");
var linksInOrderLinesTable = [];

if (orderLinesTable) { // only get the links when the table exists
    linksInOrderLinesTable = orderLinesTable.getElementsByTagName("a");
}
```

Comment: your code works fine with the if statement, thanks very much, but Chrome now says: "Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain". 
And I know that all my script tags do have the MIME type="tetx/javascript". What's up with Chrome and its over-sensitive engine? Have you ever come across that message before?

Comment: If you include your scripts via the `src` attribute, Chrome may alert you about the fact that your server doesn't set the `content-type` header correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Safari and Chrome both support the method. The object you're using it on may not be consistently retrieved, so it evaluates to null. Check how you're grabbing the object you're calling it on.

BTW.. it's not a Javascript method, it's a method in the DOM API.

EDIT:

```
document.getElementById("orderLinesTable")
```

alert what this is. Is it null?

Comment: Yes, it's gonna be null because this code is for a particular page with that "orderLinesTable" id in it. It only shows the error on other pages that haven't got that id. The problem is, the javascript file is an include file across the whole web application. The other pages shouldn't be able to implement the code since it doesn't concern them, which is what FF and Opera are doing, they ignore it. So why do they bother with Chrome and Safari?

BTW: thanks for the correction about DOM API

Comment: I've just checked with the alert and it says it is null, so what do I do? I'm stuck...

Comment: Provide the HTML. And tell us when the function is invoked. And anything else you're not telling.

Comment: Please see the below the javascript code for the HTML. It works on that page but when I'm on other pages it gives me the error mentioned. I know why, but I just don't know what to do. I've even tried "if it's 'null' do this, ...etc", but it's still not working... :(